# Unable to send SMS message [Discord]

Tags: discord

Hi please I need help I can't verify my acc in discord before Yesterday I changed my Gmail to a proton email and I deleted my number I worked fine but after I was talking to DM's and trying to add another phone number to verify I got this error telling me to verify my acc "We've detected something out of the ordinary going on, and we want to keep you and the community safe. To continue using Discord"  when I try to verify with the phone number they give me error "Unable To send an SMS message" what I need to do please I try to use different numbers but didn't works I even try to login to another Acc I have and also give me the same error "Unable to send an SMS message" Please if anyone knows solution what I need to do?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! This is something you probably better post in the Discord support forum than here as there you may get help from Discord employees or supporters.